# The Magic Eden API is only giving the symbol in the json response?

Tags: python-requests, nft

I'm trying to get floor price of an NFT collection via the Magic Eden API. I'm using python requests -
The docs for the API provide this sample code:

```
import requests

url = "http://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/DeGods/stats"

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

except the url has "runcible" instead of "DeGods".

The docs give and example response with "symbol", "floorprice",  "listedCount" and "volumeAll" in the JSON object - however, no matter what collection I try it only gives me the symbol in the response.

There was no examples headers or payload.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol of a collection is the name of the collection in lowercase, with spaces replaced with an underscore. Try with `http://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/degods/stats` and it will work.

Your code should look like this:

```
import requests

symbol = "DeGods"

url = "http://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/{symbol}/stats".format(symbol=symbol.lower().replace(" ", "_"))

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

With the above code, try another collection. E.g.`The Catalina Whale Mixer`.

That's a simplification, and it captures most of the collections. Others need a more precise approach that are too varied, and I can't go into in this answer.

As a hint, The symbol of a Magic Eden collection can be deduced from the link of the collections page.

For example, the link for the `Grim Syndicate` collection is `https://magiceden.io/marketplace/grim_syndicate`. The last segment of the link is the symbol name.

Comment: I know this is unrelated to the question, but how do you make sense of the floorprice response? By default it seems to be 9 or 10 digits long but it has no decimal point or anything - so it seems impossible to work out its price without actually looking at it's respective collection page. 

For example, 

the response for catalina whale mixer is 

```
{"symbol":"the_catalina_whale_mixer","floorPrice":86500000000,"listedCount":159,"avgPrice24hr":82828823529.41176,"volumeAll":143382661203733}
```

when the actual floorprice is 86.50

Comment: You need to divide by LAMPORTS_PER_SOL which is equivalent to 1000000000. `86.50 == 86500000000 / 1000000000`